# Colorbox and Volusion Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox, volusion

I can't figure out why my Colorbox is not displaying on a Volusion site I'm working on. I've taken the code from the site and put it into a JSFiddle and it works fine.

When it's done on the site it puts the semi-transparent overlay up and opens the colorbox but then immediately closes the box. The overlay remains as if the colorbox is up and if I use the inspect element tool in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox, the colorbox exists on the site but isn't being shown. If I click away (like use with a normal Colorbox), the overlay goes away and the site is back.

My hands are kind of tied because I can't show the site since it's for a client but does anyone know why this would occur. I don't believe it to be a jQuery conflict since it actual loads all the content and I don't know why the content doesn't show because it works fine in jsFiddle. Any help would be appreciated, I understand if this is tough without the example. Thanks.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure, it was a while back and I'm not entirely sure where the issue was (and the link isn't here since it was confidential)...

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it is hard to say, but I know that when I tried to create a cart total dialog using jQuery on a Volusion site I had problems.

In the end I had to use noConflict mode for my scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

I also ran my .js through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) since the formatting really seems to matter when inside the Volusion environment. In general I found that anything you try to do on Volusion takes a bit more poking and prodding.

Not sure if this will help, but it may be a place to start.